# Image Gallery with multiupload

Tags: 7, files, media

i have a Drupal 7 site and want to generate a image gallery.

My requirements:

- Multi File Upload
- one folder per Gallery
- only accessible for authenticated user

I tried plup and multiupload_imagefield_widget for multi file upload. This works fine except for the one folder per gallery requirement. All files are stored in the same folder.

Do you have any advices on how to achiev this goal?

Comment: [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) + The *DEV* version of [Media Browser Plus](http://drupal.org/project/media_browser_plus) + [Plupload](http://drupal.org/project/plupload) would get you pretty close I think.

Comment: plupload uploads everything in the same directory.
And i cant create Folders in media Browser Plus

Comment: Yes you can, use the **DEV** Version!

Comment: I installed the dev version. could you give me a hint, where i can define a new folder while creating a new gallery?

Comment: There's no integration with media gallery specifically (that I know of) but you can navigate to `admin/content/media/folder_list` to add/manage the folders.

Comment: http://s14.directupload.net/images/120308/t7oh3oim.png
There is no folder_list :/

Comment: http://s1.directupload.net/images/120308/ykknusik.png ...It's there for me :) I've literally just installed this on a site (5 minutes ago) and it still works fine so the latest dev version is definitely the one you should be installing.

Comment: I only installed media browser plus dev.
i also needed media dev version.
Thanks.
Would you please Copy your comment and post it as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer about that, yes you need Media dev too. I've added it is an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same problem like Jussi and i tried to set up a system with the [himuesgallery module](http://drupal.org/project/himuesgallery), the upload via ftp works great and you can build a folder system.
I tried to integrate the image folders in Drupals Private Dir and the result is that i can't see any picture anymore ... may i configured somehing wrong, but this seems not to be a solution.
May a module to restrict access to another folder help.

A long time ago i tried the [media module](http://drupal.org/project/media) and there was some other problems...
See also the Media Issues or the statement of the authors:

> Known Issues
>
> Private files: There are several issues in Media and Drupal core when the private file system is used. While these issue are being investigated and fixed, the use of the File lock module is highly recommended.

So my answer is: No, there is currently no working gallery that reachs your aims.

Answer (score 1):

[Media *DEV*](http://drupal.org/project/media) + [Media Browser Plus *DEV*](http://drupal.org/project/media_browser_plus) + [Plupload](http://drupal.org/project/plupload) would get you pretty close I think.

There's no integration with media gallery specifically (that I know of) but you can navigate to `admin/content/media/folder_list` to add/manage your list of folders. Once you've done that you'll be able to sort your uploads into the various folders using the normal media browser.

Comment: Media managment works now, but still expierencing some bugs.
For instance, i cannot create a gallery. Trying now different versions.

Comment: Yeah there are some issues with it (being in dev), it might be worth checking the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/media_browser_plus?categories=All) to see if you can spot patches for the problems you're having